# Xpath Cast node to number for mod

Tags: xpath, numbers, modulus

I have nodes that contain numbers that I would like to cast to a number and use mod. For example:

```
<item>
    <num>1</num>
</item>
<item>
    <num>2</num>
</item>
<item>
    <num>3</num>
</item>
```

I've tried:

```
num mod 3 -- returns NaN
number(num) mod 3 -- returns NaN
number(string(num)) -- returns NaN
```

Any idea if this can be done? Even if there was a way to convert to ASCII, I would take it

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Those first two should work. What XPath engine are you using?

Comment: What does plain `num` return? I bet that's NaN too. My guess is that your expressions aren't working because the context node is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`number(num) mod 3` should work. The following example files output `1 2 0` as expected.

#### XML

(saved as `input.xml`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="mod_test.xsl"?>
<items>
    <item>
        <num>1</num>
    </item>
    <item>
        <num>2</num>
    </item>
    <item>
        <num>3</num>
    </item>
</items>
```

#### XSL

(saved as `mod_text.xsl`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="//item">
    <xsl:value-of select="number(num) mod 3"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note: just `num mod 3` in the select also works.

For reference, here is the [relevant section](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#numbers) in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

> I've tried:
>
> ```
> num mod 3 -- returns NaN 
> number(num) mod 3 -- returns NaN 
> number(string(num)) -- returns NaN
> ```
>
> Any idea if this can be done?

**As no complete XML document is provided, here are my two guesses**:

1. **The context node for the relative expressions has no `num` children**. The solution is to assure that the context node is the correct one, or to use absolute XPath expression(s).
2. **The not-shown XML document is in a default namespace**. In this case the solution is to "register a namespace" (associate a string-prefix to the default namespace, say `"x"`) and then replace in your expressio(s) `num` with `x:num`.